# How to wrap text in Positioned child?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to show an image and there will be a text just next to it but my text is so long that it can't fit the screen. Here is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        title: new Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Demo"),
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 50,
            left: 25,
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  "https://reimg-teknosa-cloud-prod.mncdn.com/mnresize/200/200/productimage/125036758/125036758_0_MC/48543732.jpg"),
              height: 300,
              width: 200,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Positioned(
              top: 70,
              left: 260,
              child: Text(
                "Durum: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaB",
                style: GoogleFonts.sourceSerifPro(
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried overflow: TextOverflow.clip, did not work and I searched about Flexible and Expended but I could not place them in my code. I tried to place them instead of Container but that did not work. How can I make my text continue to down line if it won't fit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had to change the structure and use column and row for Flexible() and solved the issue but if this has an answer, I would be appraciate to know!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        title: new Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Demo"),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Durum: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaB",
                  style: GoogleFonts.sourceSerifPro(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  "https://reimg-teknosa-cloud-prod.mncdn.com/mnresize/200/200/productimage/125036758/125036758_0_MC/48543732.jpg"),
              height: 300,
              width: 200,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was what I did but without changing the structure, I assume there is no way.

Comment: What do you mean? what did you need really ? Can you upload the image did you need?

Comment: That was what I need but I was curious about doing that without using Column and Row and not changing my structure. I assume you did not see my comment before answering.

Comment: What's your problem with `Row` and `Column` ?

Comment: I don't have any. Just wanted to know is there any way to do it without them.

Comment: Yes, if your result that i write for you, i can write other methods, same result for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in your `Text` widget `softWrap: true`.

Comment: Did not work. Still can't see the end of text and does not continue to down line.